# automatically pointing the id within the yii urlManager

Tags: yii

or in other words get rid of the `/id/` in the address bar.

I have the following specified in urlManager:

`'<controller:\w+>/update/<sid:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'`

which means I need to specify the following in the url address bar:

```
mysite.com/post/update/sid/s390seret88se
```

How can I configure it so that all I need is:

```
mysite.com/post/update/s390seret88se
```

I don't want the sid to be visible in the address bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want hide `sid` only for `update` action do this

```
'<controller:\w+>/update/<sid:\w+>'=>'<controller>/update'
```

Or if you want to update for all actions use

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<sid:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'
```

Comment: getting `request is invalid` still. This is in a module, would that matter?

Comment: you said `mysite.com/post/update/sid/s390seret88se` working in the question. I dont see any module info in that url